# Evaluate an unknown operator

Tags: pattern-recognition

I have a simple question but I can't seem to be able to solve it.

Given that:

```
25 ╧ 17 = 267
35 ╧ 23 = 373
45 ╧ 15 = 465
```

what is `45 ╧ 26`?

Thanks. (P.S.: The `╧` operation does not exist, just used in the question and that's all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I see:

```
x╧y=10x+y
```

$${}{}{}{}$$

Answer (score 0):

The answer is $476$ - first number plus first digit of second number concatenated with second digit of second number i.e. $45 + 2, 6$.